# Working with shared libraries across team projects on TFS

Tags: tfs, shared-libraries, project-management

After working quite long without versioning I am trying to restructure one of my old projects and try to learn how to work with TFS. For the moment I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
$/Application
$/Application/Main (Branch)
...
$/Application/Main/Source
$/Application/Main/Source/Application
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedBinaries
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource/Library1
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource/Library1/Include
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource/Library2
$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource/Library2/Include
$/Application/Main/Source/Tool1
$/Application/Main/Source/Tool2
...
$/Application/Development (branched from Main)
```

The sourcecode of `Application` resides in `$/Application/Main/Source/Application` while storing binary dependencies such as `*.lib` and `*.dll` files in `$/Application/Main/Source/SharedBinaries`. In `$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource` there should be a directory for each used library. Right now these are only 3rd party libs such that they only provide the necessary include files and no sourcecode at all.

Now I want to create a new team project for a common library referred to as `ClassLibrary`. The `Application` will use it, but other applications too, such that directly integrating the library would definitely be no good design. Similiar to the app itself we have this hierarchy:

```
$/ClassLibrary
$/ClassLibrary/Main (Branch)
...
$/ClassLibrary/Main/Source
$/ClassLibrary/Main/Source/ClassLibrary
...
$/ClassLibrary/Development (branched from Main)
```

My very first attempts was to branch `$/ClassLibrary/Main/Source/ClassLibrary` to `$/Application/Main/Source/SharedSource` such that updating the lib, all other projects get the updated version like merging Development to Main however this doesn't work and this is a sign that I have no idea how to structure this right. **What is the general approach of handling such shared content and libraries across different team projects boundaries?**

---

*Notice: Yes, this question is another version of one I asked yesterday, which I have deleted to completely update this.*

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problems as you did. There is a Visual Studio Extension called [AIT Dependency Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/92a6416d-fc18-4b5b-9b66-fba7af728984). It's definitely a tool that can solve your problem of propagating your class library to your applications.